# Comparing strings for their similarities?

Tags: string, algorithm, list, graph, distance

I want to count the number of times there is an ocurrence of certain college course on a list of thousands of entries. The problem is the course is not always spelled the same. For example, `Computer Engineering` can be spelled `Computers Engineering`. What is a proper, elegant way to test if 2 strings are very similar?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to **canonize the strings** using [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming). The idea is - give each string its canonized form, and two different strings, that represent the same word are very likely to have the same canon form (for example, `Computer` and `Computers` will have the same cannon form, and you will get a match).

[Porter stemming algorithm](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/) is often used for canonization.

---

An alternative - is grading the strings with a distance between each other, the suggested [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) can help you with it, but personally - I'd prefer canonization.

Comment: I've used Jaro-Winkler distance, which I found by googling for Levenshtein Distance, with great results.